# Cast optimization and GCHandle

Tags: c#, casting

I have an object that provides access to an internal byte[] only through an implicit cast operator. Something like this:

```
class Thing
{
    private byte[] array;
    public static implicit operator byte[](Thing thing) => thing.array;
}
```

I need to pin that array to pass as an IntPtr:

```
void Foo(Thing thing)
{
    byte[] array = thing;  // cast to access inner byte[]
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    DoSomethingWithArray(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle));
    handle.Free();
}
```

It seems like it could be possible (in some circumstance I have not encountered) for the compiler to optimize away the cast which would result in the wrong object being pinned. Is it?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible since the cast is necessary for the program to function. What makes you think this, what would be the result of the optimization?

Comment: I think I'm just being paranoid.

Comment: Does `DoSomethingWithArray` hold a reference to the `IntPtr` even after it returns?

Comment: @RonBeyer No, it doesn't.

Comment: The reason I think it could be possible is because GCHandle.Alloc takes an Object parameter, so both (Object)thing an (byte[])thing produce and Object. The compiler might feel satisfied?

Comment: Optimizations do not change the observable behaviour of the code, and since `thing` and `array` are references to different objects, I tend to agree that the cast cannot be optimized away. Though, perhaps the internal array from `Thing` shouldn't be exposed, but rather an `IntPtr` can be made available via a method call?

Comment: The operator will most certainly be optimized away and turned into a single MOV instruction.  Nothing special about that, property getters and small methods get optimized away as well.  Doesn't matter at all, the pointer is still a reference to a byte[] and can't be anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing around a reference, so there should be no possibility that the wrong thing is pinned. The line `byte[] array = thing;` will execute as if it was written `byte[] array = operator(thing);`. It looks like you're returning a reference to the innermost array. That's what will get pinned.

Edit: The reason why it won't be optimized away is because it's not a cast anymore; it's a function call when you write your own operator like that. It's possible that the function itself may be inlined, but the behavior won't simply disappear.